# Why Is the button returning null values for my event.target in my button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, binding

When I'm clicking the button, I am getting that all the values are undefined for the "name" and the "value". I am not sure why, my binding seems correct.

I've tried changing the bindings, I've tried calling an anonymous function for the onClick and passing in the item within my map function. No luck.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const starterItems = [{ id: 1, name: 'longsword', enhancement: 4 },
{ id: 2, name: 'gauntlet', enhancement: 9 },
{ id: 3, name: 'wizard\'s staff', enhancement: 14 }];


export default class Items extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleScoreChange = this.handleScoreChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      items: starterItems
    }
  }
  handleScoreChange(e){
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    const id = name;
const newScore = value++;
const items = this.state.items.slice();
items.forEach((item) => {
  if (item[id] === name){
    item.enhancement = newScore
  }
});
this.setState(items);
};



render() {
return (
  <div>
    <h3 data-testid="title">Items</h3>
    {this.state.items.map(item => (
      <div key={item.id}>
        <div name={item.name}data-testid="item">{item.name}</div>
        <div name={item.enhancement}data-testid="enhancement" value= 
{item.enhancement}>{item.enhancement}
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.handleScoreChange}>Enhance</button>
       </div>
    ))}
  </div>

   );

  };
 }
```

I am expecting the value of the item passed through to +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.target` is the DOM reference for the button

including `name` and `value` as attributes for the `div` are not necessary

If you want to get the values for the current `name` and `enhancement` when clicking you can add a binding

```js
{
  this.state.items.map(item => {
    const onClick = this.handleScoreChange.bind(this, item.name, item.enhancement)
    return (
      <div key={item.id}>
        <div name={item.name}data-testid="item">{item.name}</div>
        <div name={item.enhancement}data-testid="enhancement" value={item.enhancement}>{item.enhancement}</div>
        <button onClick={onClick}>Enhance</button>
      </div>
    )
  )
}
...
handleScoreChange(name, enhancement) {
  // your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <button onClick={()=>this.handleScoreChange(...item)}>Enhance</button>
```

please try this i am sure this will work for you

thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it said I was trying to spread something that wasn't able to be spread for some reason.

Comment: okay but i think what i have suggested is similar to above answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

This Solution Worked. Slight modification from what Omar mentioned. Thank you

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const starterItems = [{ id: 1, name: 'longsword', enhancement: 4 },
{ id: 2, name: 'gauntlet', enhancement: 9 },
{ id: 3, name: 'wizard\'s staff', enhancement: 14 }];


export default class Items extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      items: starterItems
    }
  }
  enhanceItem(passedItem) {
    const newScore = passedItem.enhancement + 1;
    const items = this.state.items.slice(); /* creates a copy of state that we can change */
    items.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.id === passedItem.id) {
        return item.enhancement = newScore
      }
    });
    this.setState(items);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3 data-testid="title">Items</h3>
        {
          this.state.items.map(item => {
            const onClick = this.enhanceItem.bind(this, item)
            /* this line above binds the item with the onClick Function */
            /* notice below, I had to put a return since I added the above code */
            return (
              <div key={item.id}>
                <div data-testid="item">{item.name}</div>
                <div data-testid="enhancement">{item.enhancement}</div>
                {/* We can use the "data=testid" as a way to grab an item, since it won't impact the html any */}
                <button onClick={onClick}>Enhance</button>
              </div>
            )
          })};
        </div>

    );
  };
}
```